# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, How to install BCM 4365 rev 1 driver?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers

I followed this guide: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

When I went to "Additional Drivers", and under the "Broadcom Corporation : BCM43142 802.11b/g/n" it says "This device is using an alternative driver. But before it said, this device is not working or something like that.

This was a fresh install and the only things I did were all in the guide of "Installing Broadcom Wireless Devices."

But later, I found out that this device isn't working at all from this bug, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/923809.

Plus I get the result after installing "bcmwl-kernel-source",

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.16.0-38-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
```

Will post whatever you need me to post.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add there output of `cat /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom/build/make.log` terminal command there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is now solved!

After numerous reinstalls, I finally got the "sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source" to finally go through!

What I did differently this time is when it asked me to install, I check marked both the boxes, Download and Install when it asked me about the proprietary devices.

Comment: Check this as your answer rather than editing the title to say "SOLVED".   The little "Accept Answer" check mark should be below the voting options.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot with previous kernel using grub menu and install `bcmwl-kernel-source`. This version of bcmwl did build with previous kernels.

They just pushed 3.16.0-18, and there must be some regression.

Comment: Hey Pilot6,  How would you exactly do that?  I just recently installed Ubuntu so i'm not really sure how to do what you just did.  Your advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pressing Shift when trying to get into the Grub menu doesn't work.  I tried to change the timeout thing but either way, it didn't work.